# PostgreSQL selecting empty fields of integer type

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and I need to select all the rows with an empty value for the `fk_fc_id` field (as a prelude to deleting them),

```
    Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 di_timestamp  | timestamp without time zone |
 di_item_value | character varying(10)       |
 fk_fc_id      | integer                     |
 di_id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('data_item_di_id_seq1'::regclass)
```

However this doesn't work,

```
# select fk_fc_id,di_timestamp,di_item_value from data_item where fk_fc_id="";
ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...di_timestamp,di_item_value from data_item where fk_fc_id="";
                                                                    ^
```

Trying `Null` doesn't work either.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to sort this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: select fk_fc_id,di_timestamp,di_item_value from data_item where fk_fc_id is null

Comment: Double quotes aren't used for strings in PostgreSQL. Single quotes are used for strings. But you shouldn't be comparing zero-length strings to integers! And comparing values with `null` using the `=` operator will always return `null` and cause that row to be excluded.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is not really database administration related, nor is it really about PostgreSQL, but as @foibs answered, you should have a look at [IS NULL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp):

```
 SELECT fk_fc_id,
        di_timestamp,
        di_item_value  
 FROM data_item  
 WHERE fk_fc_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Ah, I was trying = Null rather than is Null. Thanks,

Comment: Both (=;IS) works fine in 9.4

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quote:

```
SELECT fk_fc_id,
        di_timestamp,
        di_item_value  
 FROM data_item  
 WHERE fk_fc_id=''
```

Comment: Technically, you are right, a string in SQL should be delimited with single quotes. However, in this specific case the OP shouldn't compare to a string (empty or not) in the first place, because the column in question is defined as `integer`. As you can read in the comments under the accepted answer, the OP decided to try comparison to an empty string only because they hadn't figured out how to correctly compare to null (which is what they were actually after).